# avoiding repetion while declaring maps

Tags: clojure, environ

I'm setting up config map using [environ](https://github.com/weavejester/environ) for fetching up env variables. Since *environ* normalizes upper case to lowercase and "_" characters to "-", I ended up with repetitions of keywords

```
(def config {:consumer-key (env :consumer-key)
             :keystore-password (env :consumer-key)
             :ssl-keystore-password (env :ssl-keystore-password)
             :ssl-certificate-name (env :ssl-certificate-name)
             :callback-url (env :callback-url)
             :mp-private-key (env :mp-private-key)
             :merchant-checkout-id (env :merchant-checkout-id)
             :is-sandbox (env :is-sandbox)})
```

is there a way to prevent this repetition? maybe a function which receives a keyword and returns some kind of key value pair for the map?

Comment: Could you use [`select-keys`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/select-keys) to create the `config` map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, since `env` is a map you can just use `select-keys` with a list of keys to copy:

```
(def config
  (select-keys env [:consumer-key :is-sandbox
                    :keystore-password :ssl-keystore-password :ssl-certificate-name
                    :callback-url :mp-private-key :merchant-checkout-id]))
```

Alan Thompson's approach is reasonable if you have an arbitrary function rather than specifically a map.

Comment: Since he is using the `environ` library then `env` is indeed a function:  https://github.com/weavejester/environ#usage

Comment: If i remember correctly, it ic a map really. "Lets pull the database connection details from the key :database-url on the environ.core/env map." (From docs).. so @amalloy's answer should be correct

Comment: It's definitely a map: https://github.com/weavejester/environ/blob/master/environ/src/environ/core.clj#L39

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it by defining a helper function:

```
(def env {:consumer-key   1
          :ssl-key        2
          :mp-private-key 3})

(def key-list (keys env))

(defn extract-from
  [src-fn keys]
  (into (sorted-map)
    (for [key keys]
      {key (src-fn key)} )))

(println "result:" (extract-from env key-list))

=> result: {:consumer-key 1, :mp-private-key 3, :ssl-key 2}
```

Note that for testing purposes I used a trick and substituted a ***map*** `env` for the ***function*** `env` from the `environ` library. This works since a map can act like a function when looking up its keys. It will still work for an actual function like `environ.core/env`.